# Hiding an Iframe by Default

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

In one of the pages I need to have an iframe, but when the user loads the page I want it to be hidden by default. Right now I have a hide and show button to hide and show the iframe, but it is shown by default. How can I hide it by default?

Here's the code I have for the two buttons

```
<input type="button" value="Show Graph" onClick="$('graph').show();">
<input type="button" value="Hide Graph" onClick="$('graph').hide();">
```

Answer (score 6):

Did you try to use CSS like this?

```
iframe {
   display:none;}
```

Though that depends if you want to have the area reserved too. With a sketch it would be easier to know.

You can hide on load with jQuery, too.

```
function(){$('graph').hide();}
```

Comment: I still want to be able to show/hide it, I just want to hide it be default. Would this work for that?

Comment: @Reti - Yes, using the display property would hide all the iframes on the page when the page loads.

Answer (score 3):

Also - since you are already using jQuery you could just simply hide the iFrame on the page load like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
     $('#graph').hide();
});
</script>
```

**Working demo :** [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gRTah/)

*So you will need to make sure of the following changes:*

**Iframe :**

Add `id="graph"` to your iframe.

**onClick Events:**

Add `onClick="$('#graph').show();"` and `onClick="$('#graph').hide();"` respectively

Comment: I've tried adding this inside the head tag and right above the graph, but it's not working. I reload the page and it still shows up.

Comment: It seems I had left out the <script> tags, is the demo working for you?

Comment: The demo works for me, but it doesn't work in my application... weird.

Comment: Did you try wrapping the code in the <script> tags? Also - you will need to ensure that the id of your iframe = "graph", and make sure to add the #graph instead of graph in your button onClick events

Comment: When  change the onclick to #graph, it stops working, even though the id='graph', and even though I put what you told me to for hiding by default, it doesn't work (even if I try graph instead of #graph). It's confusing as to why it doesn't work...

Comment: That's bizarre. So you have your iframe with id="graph", and both of your onClick methods look like this : $('#graph').show() and $('#graph').hide() ? If this isn't working you might want to put a larger example so we can troubleshoot it.

Answer (score 0):

If you put this in your `<head>` tag, it should hide it for you

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('graph').hide();
});
</script>
```

Although you might was to double-check that you're just using `'graph'` - in jQuery that would refer to a `<graph>` element; `'#graph'` would refer to the iframe with the id "graph"

Comment: The iframe's id is "graph", but even if I change it to #graph, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways I know:

1. You set the height and width to 0.
2. Set an ID for the iframe (for example "hideframe") and in the head or in external stylesheet add this

   ```
   #hideframe{display: none;}
   ```
3. Use jQuery

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){        
      $("#hideframe").css("display", "none");        
   });
   ```

   Or

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#hideframe").hide();
   });
   ```

Make sure jQuery is actually included in the head of your page. Many times I hear people say something doesn't work in jQuery. It turns out their URLs to the jQuery library were wrong so make sure you don't fall into this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing someting.. but you can make a self invoking a jQuery function as follows

`(function (){
    $('iframe').hide();
})();`